# ASP.NET Core default/fallback route

Tags: asp.net-core

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 app that's running IdentityServer RazorPages and a React SPA.

The IdentityServer pages are set up like this

```
                    // Case: Identity endpoints, Identity RazorPages, and NOT webAPI.
                    appTenant.UseWhen(
                        httpContext => (httpContext.RequestIsForIdentityServerUi() || httpContext.RequestIsForIdentityServerEndpoint()
                        //|| (httpContext.RequestIsForAPIEndpoint()) && !httpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments(new PathString("/api/global") /* API on subdomain available for parallel running until TTAMIS is switched over to api subdomain. */),
                        ),
                        appIdentityServer =>
                        {
                            appIdentityServer.UseRouting();
                            appIdentityServer.UseAuthentication();
#pragma warning disable ASP0001 // UseAuthorization IS called between UseRouing and UseEndpoints!
                            appIdentityServer.UseAuthorization();
#pragma warning restore ASP0001
                            appIdentityServer.UseIdentityServer();
                            appIdentityServer.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
                                {
                                    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
                                    // Do not fall through to React app:
                                    // If an Identity page was requested but not found then reutrn 404.
                                    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Identity/Error/404"); // Doens't work.
                                });
                        }
                    );
```

with the SPA stuff afterwards.
Therefore if an identity route doesn't match then it falls through and the SPA is served, but I don't want this behaviour -- I want to show the error page if an identity page is requested that doesn't exist.

[image]

I've tried adding

```
endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/Identity/Error/404");
```

but then when I go to a URL that doesn't exit I get

> `InvalidOperationException: Cannot find the fallback endpoint specified by route values: { page: /Identity/Error/404, area: }.`

which is obviously a lie becuase `/Identity/Error` *does* exist.

Can this be made to work? How?

**update**

```
MapFallbackToAreaController("get", "Error", "Identity");
```

also doesn't work, neither `""` nor '"get"`, nor creating a new method` GetFallback`and using`"fallback"` as the action parameter.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement,it should be

```
app.MapFallbackToAreaPage("/Error", "Identity");
```